# Android : setText on TextView which programmatically generated

Tags: android, textview, programmatically-created

so I want to have a X number of TextView which is programmatically created and added to its parrent layout, and set each textView with different text depends on its id.

I already manage to created and added X number of TextView into its parrent Layout ,although I'm not sure do I manage to give each of them different id which I created manually with simple string manipulation and store them inside a HashMap.

next step, I try to get each TextView with `findViewById()` using the id from HashMap and setText each TextView but I have no idea why my TextView is still blank. I already try to hardcode the text directly when the TextView is created but it still give me blank view, but this seems only happen with TextView, I also tried add X number ImageView programmatically with the same way I add the TextView, and setImageResourse depends on each id, and it works

honestly, I dont know where my mistake and I hope you can point me in the right direction .Thanks

I'm using minimal SDK Jelly Bean 4.2.2(API 17)

here's my onCreate()

```
int allEventNumber,imageId,textNameId,textDateId,textTappedId = -1;
    LinearLayout layoutUtama,eventLayout,detailLayout;
    ImageView thumbnailImageView;
    TextView textViewName,textViewDate,textViewTapped;
    String  imageIdKey,textNameIdKey,textDateIdKey,textTappedIdKey,textDate,textTapped,textName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);
        HashMap<String,Integer> keyId = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        keyId = initAll(keyId);
        fillAllById(allEventNumber,keyId);

    }
```

initAll(HashMap)

```
public HashMap<String,Integer> initAll(HashMap<String,Integer> hMap){
        allEventNumber = 6;     //hardcode
        layoutUtama = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_utama);
        hMap = insertLayout(hMap,allEventNumber);
        return hMap;
    }
```

insertLayout(HashMap, int)

```
public HashMap<String,Integer> insertLayout(HashMap<String ,Integer> hMap, int jumlahEvent){
        //

        for (int i =1;i<= jumlahEvent;i++){

            eventLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            eventLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            eventLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            thumbnailImageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageIdKey = "key_image_view_" + i;
            imageId = View.generateViewId();
            hMap.put(imageIdKey,imageId);
            thumbnailImageView.setId(imageId);
            thumbnailImageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            detailLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            detailLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(15,0,0,0);
            detailLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            detailLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            textViewName = new TextView(this);
            textNameIdKey = "key_text_view_name_" + i;
            textNameId = View.generateViewId();
            hMap.put(textNameIdKey,textNameId);
            textViewName.setId(textNameId);
            textViewName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            textViewName.setTextSize(R.dimen.event_name_text_size);
            textViewName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            detailLayout.addView(textViewName);
            eventLayout.addView(thumbnailImageView);
            eventLayout.addView(detailLayout);
            layoutUtama.addView(eventLayout);

        }
        return hMap;
    }
```

fillAllById(int,HashMap)

```
public void fillAllById(int allEventNumber,HashMap<String,Integer> hMap){
        for (int i=1;i<=allEventNumber;i++){
            imageIdKey = "key_image_view_" + i;
            textNameIdKey = "key_text_view_name_" + i;
            imageId = hMap.get(imageIdKey);

            textNameId = hMap.get(textNameIdKey);

            thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageId);
            textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(textNameId);

            thumbnailImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbnail_event3);
            textName = "Name Event";

            textViewName.setText(textName);
        }
    }
```

and my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.hansel.tapbandung_v00.Event">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_utama"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">






            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: interesting. have you tried logging the key,value pair you are saving & then what do you get while retrieving?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something that Android's [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) (or ListView) already handles well. If you have a list of data, then you can just provide that as the adapter for the RecyclerView and everything else will be handled automatically.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha yes , I got the matching ID between the creation and the setText

Comment: @Anonsage I just take a look at some example about `ListView` and I think you're right, I'm working on it now